# Handle global variable in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a node.js server that reads messages from a rabbitmq server. Every message contains an url that returns a json object whit specifications to download some jsx code.

The node.js server gets the code from the urls and compiles it with webpack.
My problem is that I need to keep aware of the information of the json objects in the webpack compilation instance, because I need to print the downloaded objects in the index page.

- Node Server -- Get messages --> RabbitMQ Server
- RabbitMQ Server -- Return messages --> Node Server
- Node Server -- Get code [from URL] --> URL service
- URL service -- Return code --> Node Server
- Node Server: Compile downloaded code.

I don't know if I was clear. I tried to use global variables and module.exports, but did not work. Maybe I am missing something, I am a kind of beginner in JS, node and webpack.

Comment: Are you asking how to reference specific messages across multiple modules?

Comment: Basically I want to put the information of the messages in an array for example, and be able to read the array globally in the code that will be compiled.

Comment: It's hard to suggest help without any actual code, or seeing what you tried. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I'd suggest initializing your modules using a function for each that accepts an event emitter as an argument, and then listening to it for whenever data the module needs access to gets returned.

Answer (score -1):

Could you cache those in memory, that way they would be available to access.

One of the popular module is [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache.)

Though memory caching comes in with it's own set of limitations.

Hope I understood the question correct.